# Why is my IIS6 Site Not Using AppPool Credentials?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, iis

I have a site that is running under the root site's credentials instead of the one in its AppPool and cannot figure out why.  This is not a problem on other servers.

Configuration:

- Windows Server 2003
- Site (test.domain.com) running in custom AppPool using a domain service account (domain\iis-user)
- Application running under a separate AppPool with different credentials (domain\app-user)

When I browse to test.domain.com/app, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name shows domain\iis-user instead of domain\app-user.

I've checked that both user accounts are in the proper IIS security groups on the server and have tried setting SPNs.  Changing the account for the AppPool to a known good account made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps write out the PID as well, and just check it's running in the App Pool you think it's running in.

Identity can be a secondary issue - for example, if Anonymous is enabled, the request may be impersonating the Anonymous user account, which may coincide with another ID.

Likewise, UNC credentials for a remote share might cause the credentials to be used with - for example - ASP.Net.

Comment: Good idea.  We've verified the AppPool is what we expect and anonymous access is set to use the same service account as the AppPool.  I will have to check on the path credentials later.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you've got `<identity impersonate="true" />` configured either in the site or root site `web.config`.

This could also be configured in `machine.config` file located in:

`%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`

Comment: The config files did not have impersonate tags.  We tried adding it and it made no difference.